# Пагинатор в django

Tags: django

Как обработать страницы в пагинаторе django? У меня есть много моделей

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
rep = models.SmallIntegerField()
text = models.TextField()
```

В форме есть первая дата и вторая, которые передаются во вью. Пагинатор должен выводить среднюю репутацию первой даты в промежутке времени (те статьи, которые написаны 1 февр 2016 с 10:00 по 1 февр2016 20:00, 2 февр 2016 с 10:00 по 2 февр2016 20:00 и тд) суммируется n rep / n кол-во статей (те среднее значение rep), дальше берется след. дата (тк их много, то сразу все вычислить - очень долго)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пагинатор берет ваш подготовленный queryset, вычисляет количество записей в нем, берет (если есть) текущее смещение из request, смотрит можно ли произвести смещение, и выводит из БД нужное количество записей взятые с вычисленным смещением.

А вот подготовить запрос, то что надо "пагинировать" - ваша задача, пагинатор тут непричем.

Comment: Решил эту проблему, вычисляя среднее значение во view